# Memory management in Apache+Perl

Tags: apache-2.2, memory-usage, mod-perl

I have a web farm that uses Apache 2.2.15 and mod_perl-2.0.4. I need to know if there is a comparable perl module to [`Apache::GTopLimit`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Apache::GTopLimit) for mod_perl-2.x.

I have searched Google and other sites, and have not found anything yet. What I need to do is limit the amount of memory any one worker can consume. If it exceeds the threshold, then I want the worker to die.

I have already set the `MaxRequestsPerChild` value, but that does not prevent a worker from eating up all the memory on the box.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got Apache worker processes running away with all your memory in mod_perl, you've probably got bigger issues with your underlying application code. You shouldn't need to be cycling Apache workers that manually, unless your ratio of requests to workers is very low - in which case, adjusting that ratio by decreasing the number of workers might help with your issue.

All that aside, is there anything stopping you from just `apachectl graceful`-ing Apache every *n* hours? This terminates all the existing Apache workers as soon as they become idle, spawns new ones; it's a very direct-action approach to managing the worker processes, if fixing the underlying mod_perl issue isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

For workers that are separate process, `ulimit` would work at stopping their memory growth.